# Why is django adding two slashes at the end of my urls?

Tags: html, django

I'm new to django and I'm trying to develop my first website. I've searched for similar questions but I couldn't find any (or maybe I've only searched the wrong query). What I'm here to asking is why django is adding a final slash into my url? and why is it doing this just in few occasions?
I'd want to explain you better what it's happening to me.

This is my **urls.py** (a portion)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", home, name="home"),
    path("new/", new, name="new"),
    path("attachements/<str:pk>/<str:var>/", attachements, name="attachements"),
    path("new_2_4/<str:pk>/<str:var>/", new_2_4, name="new_2_4"),
    path("new_4e2/<str:pk>/<str:var>//", new_4e2, name="new_4e2"),
    # others
]
```

In my **template.html** I've created  tag which allows me to go from a page to others, for example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:powderblue;">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'attachements' att.id var%}">Allegati</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:powderblue;">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'new_2_4' att.id var %}">4</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:powderblue;">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'new_4e2' att.id var %}">4.2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div style="position:relative; left:20px;">
  <a class="btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'new_2_4' att.id var %}">&#x2190;</a>
  <a class="btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'new_4e3' att.id var %}">&#x2192;</a>
</div>
```

When I first have designed the whole thing, my url for 'new_4e2' didn't have two final slashes: I've had to add one final manually because django was giving me a 404 error, telling that the url '.../new_4e2/x/y//' didn't exists. Can you tell me why django added two final slashes instead of 1? Why this wasn't do for the 'new_2_4' page?

I'm asking this because I have another template in which I've used again the  tag to refer to the 'new_4e2' page and this time django applies just one slash, leading me to the 404 error.

Hope I was clear and thank you in advance.

Comment: Just something to test: If you write `{{ var }}` directly somewhere in your template, has `var` a trailing slash?

Comment: It's mughe be because of `javascript` extensions as there `var` is used to define variables.

Comment: @Boldewyn I've just tried and no, it doesn't

Comment: Why do you have two trainling slashes in path('new_4e2/<str:pk>/<str:var>//', new_4e2, name="new_4e2") ?

Comment: I've had to add them otherwise django would raised an 404 error because it could not find the page 'new_4e2/<str:pk>/<str:var>//'

Comment: Django would raise a 404 error like that if you navigate to such a page (e.g. by hand). Get rid of that extra slash in your `urls.py` and look through the `<a href="">`s you're printing, in case there's e.g. `href="{% url ... %}/"` somewhere.

Comment: I've looked everywhere but I don't have any of these problems in <a href="">

Comment: Great – you should then be able to just get rid of the extra slash in your `urls`. Django will generate correct URLs, but it of course can't help you if you manually navigate to `new_4e2/foo/bar//////` (extra slashes for emphasis).

Comment: Sorry guys, I've made a very trivial error in views.py. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I came here with this same question and made the exact same mistake! Thank goodness this question exists